# Is it possible to map Hibernate <component> column to a custom user type?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, usertype

I have defined a custom user type that works fine when used properties of my entities. For instance:

```
 <class name="com.my.sample" table="MY_TABLE">
    ...
    <property name="foo" type="myCustomUserType">
 </class>
```

I'm needing something like this:

```
 <class name="com.my.sample" table="MY_OTHER">
    ...
    <component name="myAddress" class="com.my.sample.Address">
       <property name="street" column="MY_OTHER_ADRR_STREET" />
       <property name="foo" type="myCustomUserType" column="MY_OTHER_ADRR_COLUMN" />
    </component>
 </class>
```

Obviously, I'm supposing that `myCustomUserType` is properly defined in the .HBM file. Is it possible to map a `<component>` property like this?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it works fine. It is also possible to map `<component>` properties using relationships such as `<many-to-one>`. The mapping was somethig like this:

```
<component name="myAddress" class="com.my.sample.Address" >
    <property name="aSimpleDate" column="TBL_ADDR_SIMPLE_DATE" type="date" />
    <many-to-one class="OtherClass" name="otherClass" >
        <column name="TBL_ADDR_OTHER_CLASS_ID" precision="9" scale="0"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="foo" column="TLB_ADDR_FOO" type="myCustomUserType" />
</component>
```

Unfortunatelly, the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component) is not very obvious about this.